# JAXB created objects from XML tags that are not mapped to the object root element @XmlRootElement

Tags: jaxb

I have a problem.

I have the following XML:

```
<vehicles>
   <Train name="train1" />
  <Train name="train2" />
   <Train name="train3" />
   <Car name="car1" />
   <Car name="car2" />
   <Car name="car3" />
</vehicles>
```

I created an object:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Car")
public class Car 
{
   private String name;

   public Car() { super(); }

   @XmlAttribute(name="name")
   public String getName() { return name; }

   public String setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

Now I am trying to use JAXB in order to generate Car objects from the XML calling the following method:

```
bindObjectsFromXml(file, Car.class);

public static <T> List<T> bindObjectsFromXml(File file, Class<T> klazz, String[] rootElementsNames) throws Exception
{
    List<T> objects = new LinkedList<T>();

    XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = getXMLStreamReader(file);
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(klazz);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

    xmlStreamReader.nextTag();

    for ( String rootElement : rootElementsNames ) // there might be more than one root that we want to skip
    {
        xmlStreamReader.require( XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT, null, rootElement );
        xmlStreamReader.nextTag();
    }

    while ( xmlStreamReader.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT )
    {
        JAXBElement<T> jaxbElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader, klazz);
        T klazzInstance = jaxbElement.getValue();
        objects.add( klazzInstance );

        if (xmlStreamReader.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS) 
        {
            xmlStreamReader.next();
        }
    }

    return objects;
}
```

The problem is that I get Car object also from Train.

I don't understand why the unmarshaller ignores the @XmlRootElement(name="Car")?

Can you please help me with this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Your parameters for `bindObjectsFromXml` don't match. You're calling it with 2 arguments, and declaring 3 parameters.

Comment: Also, "I get Car object also from Train" doesn't make sense. Please explain more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your `JAXBContext` is aware of all the classes that you want to map to.  In your example code you build the `JAXBContext` on `Car.class` so it will not be aware of `Train.class`.  You will need to do the following:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Car.class, Train.class);
```